# Variable and string as array key

Tags: php, arrays, string, key, string-conversion

I have a problem concerning array keys. I'm trying to result the following array:

```
$options = array(
    'number 3' => 'number 3',
    'number 6' => 'number 6',
    'number 9' => 'number 9',
    'number 12' => 'number 12'
);
```

I'm using the following function:

```
function number_count() {

    $array = array();

    for( $i = 3 ; $i+3 ; $i <= 12 ) {
        $string_i = print_r($i, true);
        $array[$string_i . 'px'] = $string_i . 'px';
    }

    return $array;
}

    $options= number_count();
```

I know there is some serious error that I can't understand because the page is blocking when I try to execute the code. How I can insert a variable and key, and variable and value in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually an error in your `for`-loop...

It should be:

```
for ($i = 3;$i <= 12; $i = $i + 3) {
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, I didn't saw that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the results of `print_r` as an associative index. You can just use `$i`:

```
for ($i = 3; $i <= 12; $i + 3) {
    $array[$i . 'px'] = $i . 'px';
}
```

Also, as pointed out by Marty, the increment code should appear as the third expression in your `for` loop (you have it as the second, so the loop will run infinitely).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
+1 I didn't know that there can be a string and integer in the array key.

Comment: PHP will automatically cast the integer to a string when using the concatenation operator.